# AttributeRouting does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, routes

I put `[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("faq.html")]` on my action Faq.

However when I go to

```
localhost/faq.html
```

I get a 404 http not found error and I can't find my custom routes in localhost/routes.axd.

How can i fix this ?

thanks !

updated:
here is my faq action

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 120)]
    [AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("faq.html")]
    public virtual ActionResult FAQ(int id = 0){
        //some code here 
    }
```

Comment: How did you installed AttributeRouting? With nuget? Have you added `routes.MapAttributeRoutes();` in your Global.asax or in your `WebActivator.App_Start`?

Comment: yes , i installed it by nuget

Comment: And you have the `routes.MapAttributeRoutes();` call in the right place?

Comment: Can you post your Faq controller and your faq action code with the attribute usage? Because it should just work.

Comment: i didn't modify the default attributerouting.cs file in the app_start folder

Comment: I only have one idea left: is your `FAQ` is inside of a Controller? So it's a method of a class which inherits form `Controller`? And where is this in your project structure?

Comment: yes , inside site controller, i have a working version on my server (http://gtx-light.jp/routes.axd) , i compared web.config .....

Comment: i solved it unexpectedly, <compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.0">  remove  optimizeCompilations="true" , but i don't know why .....

Comment: "The drawback is that there are some edge cases where it does not do the right thing" --[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/04/15/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 120)]
[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("faq.html/{id?}")]
public virtual ActionResult FAQ(int id = 0){
    //some code here 
}
```

or remove "id" parameter from FAQ method.

[Explanation for AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Optional-Route-Parameters)